# ELMAH on MongoDB web interface throw exception

Tags: mongodb, logging, error-handling, elmah

after configure logs to *MongoDB* using ELMAH on *MongoDB* nuget package 
it successfully log to *MongoDB* collection but when trying to access the Web interface it gives me the following exception:

> Command 'create' failed: a collection 'collectionname' already exists (response: { "note" : "the autoIndexId option is deprecated and
>   will be removed in a future release", "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "a
>   collection 'collectionname' already exists", "code" : 48, "codeName" :
>   "NamespaceExists" })

i don't know why each time it try to create the collection 
the web config configuration for elmah:

```
 <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.FallbackErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah.FallbackErrorLog" />
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    <!--<section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />-->
  </sectionGroup>

 <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
<elmah>


  <security allowRemoteAccess="true" />

  <errorLog type="Elmah.FallbackErrorLog, Elmah.FallbackErrorLog">
    <add type="Elmah.MongoErrorLog, Elmah.MongoDB" connectionStringName="elmah-mongodb"  />
    <add type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="C:\MyApp\logs\ElmahFallback" />
  </errorLog>
</elmah>
<location path="logs" inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
      </httpHandlers>


      <authorization>
        <!--<allow roles="*" />-->
        <allow users="*" />  
      </authorization>

    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="ELMAH" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="logs" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

Comment: Were you able to find the solution to this?  I'm currently having the same issue..

Answer (score 0):

this error is by MongoDB 3.2 and up decrepted function (related by indexes when you create a new collection), try with 3.0 mongos's version or change the mongo's driver. I'm using this package **Install-Package elmah.mongodb** in visual studio nuget package console and mongo 3.0 version in c#.net and it's running perfectly.

I hope that it help you!!! good luck.